# c++ segmentation fault using condition_variable with the -static linkage flag

Tags: c++, g++, static-linking, libstdc++, conditional-variable

I compiled and linked this simple program using g++ in a Raspberry Pi 4 running on the ARMv8-A.

compiler: g++ -Wall -O0 -g3 -std=c++11 -c Main.cpp

linker: g++ -static -o "bugTest.elf" ./Main.o

Compiler version:

g++ (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110

Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

struct TempX
{
    std::condition_variable cvx;
};

int main()
{
    TempX *x = new TempX;
    std::cout << "0 done" << std::endl;
    delete x;

    std::cout << "1 done test" << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

I got segmentation fault using the cross compiler aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ (or SIGABRT using the g++ compiler on the Raspberry Pi 4) at the line delete x;

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00000000004a9810 in raise ()
(gdb) where
#0  0x00000000004a9810 in raise ()
#1  0x0000000000400b78 in abort ()
#2  0x0000000000482178 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() ()
#3  0x0000000000480e6c in __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) ()
#4  0x0000000000480ed0 in std::terminate() ()
#5  0x000000000040b790 in std::condition_variable::wait(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&) ()
#6  0x0000000000401454 in TempX::~TempX (this=0x58a040,
    __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at Main.cpp:4
#7  0x0000000000401364 in main () at Main.cpp:14
```

But I didn't get any error if I linked it without using the -static flag.

I got the same error with the -static flag using either the compiler g++ on the Raspberry Pi 4 directly or using a cross compiler aarch64-linux-gnu-g++.

Could anyone explain why?

Comment: Can you try adding `-pthread` option as an option to your linker options?

Comment: adding -pthread or -lpthread to both compiler and linker or only either one got the same seg fault. the flag "-static" is the culpit here. anyone know why?

Comment: Wait, wait, wait... why is `~TempX()` invoking `std::condition_variable::wait` in your call stack when it's clearly not getting called in your code.  Are you 100% certain the code you are showing is the code you actually compiled that generates that runtim error?  **I think you have some code in a destructor that you aren't showing us.**

Comment: it's weird. I know. the dtor() somehow calls the wait(), not sure why.  i suspected a bug in the compiler?

Comment: Are you 100% certain that you didn't declare or define a destructor for `TempX`?  Otherwise, this might be a toolchain issue...

Comment: I am very certain that the posted code above is the only code I compiled and linked.  I have a way larger code based with this seg fault. I created this Main.cpp only to narrow down the problem. the above code is exactly the same code that got the error above. something is wrong with the g++ or toolchain i guess

Comment: Another thing to do.  Compile and link with `-g` and see if the callstack changes. Can you do that and share the callstack again?

Comment: i did the -g rather than the -g3. same result with same backtrace above

Comment: This is something I still don’t understand. I have 0 code calling any of the unique lock or wait function.   I did call them in my original code. Let me test this code in another fresh raspberry pi

Comment: I used another Raspberry Pi that had nothing to do with this program before. I experienced the exact same problem with the same call stack when I compiled with the "-static" flag.    I did as suggested to combine both the compiler and linker into one line: g++ -o bugTest.elf Main.cpp -Wall -g3 -std=c++11 -pthread.  This did not have any problem as expected.  But when I did: g++ -static -o bugTest.elf Main.cpp -Wall -g3 -std=c++11 -pthread It got the exact same error with backtrace with wait and unique_lock<std::mutex>&).  But my code doesn't have any of the wait() and unique_lock() function.

Comment: Seems to be same in compiler explorer too: https://godbolt.org/z/PeMdY7eW1

Comment: @KIIV, nice find on the online compiler. i tried 5 different online compilers and none of them had the problem.  this compiler explorer is the first online compiler that could generate the same error.

Comment: @273K, the stack trace is the exact stack track matching to the file lines and contents. the stack trace show the wait() and unique_lock mutext etc are NOT in the code at all.  this is making no sense to me too

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/74Ye97jvE - is it the minimized example?

Comment: @273K, your one line code also made the segfault...wow ...

Comment: See that issue discussed and the work around https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=274171 clang `-static -stdlib=libc++ -pthread` works well

Comment: confirmed. putting unused pthread calls suggested by the gcc bug report solved the issue.    @273K, i am not using clang and compiling with "-stdlib=libc++" with g++ says uncognized command=line option "-stdlib=libc++".

Comment: You may post a self-answer, I would vote up

Comment: I am trying to find another solution rather than putting unused pthread calls there because I am getting a lot of warning: argment 1 null where non-null expected [-Wnonnull] in all those unused pthread_cond_xxxx functions.

Comment: @alien You should really post your answer as **an answer** (below) instead of putting an answer in the question.  You will likely get some positive reputation from the effort.

Comment: @Drew Dormann. Thanks for the hint. I didn't see the answer my question button at the bottom yesterday and I just saw it today.

Answer (score 3):

Answer and Update: Thanks to multiple people for the prompt answers. There is a bug in the glibc where the condition variable does not work well with the "-static" flag. This bug has been around for more than 10 years.

See bug reports and discussions here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=274171

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58909

The solution available is either not use the "-static" flag in the linker, or use some unused `pthread_cond_xxx()` functions.

For me, using an unused `pthread_cond_destroy()` solved the problem with just one warning about using `nullptr` in the non-null expected argument.

```
#include <pthread.h>
void pthread_cond_bug() {
        pthread_cond_signal((pthread_cond_t *) nullptr);
        pthread_cond_init((pthread_cond_t *) nullptr,
                          (const pthread_condattr_t *) nullptr);
        pthread_cond_destroy((pthread_cond_t *) nullptr);
        pthread_cond_timedwait((pthread_cond_t *) nullptr, (pthread_mutex_t *)
                               nullptr, (const struct timespec *) nullptr);
        pthread_cond_wait((pthread_cond_t *) nullptr, (pthread_mutex_t *) nullptr);
}
```